# Настройка Ruby On Rails сервера с NGINX и UNICORN на VPS

Tags: nginx, vps, ruby-on-rails

Доброго времени суток.
Я хочу поднять сервер NGINX и UNICORN на VPS.
И использую для этого Ubuntu 13.
Я уже научился развертывать эти сервера и даже поднял сервер работающий кое как =(.
Сейчас я хочу развернуть вменяемый сервер(без свалки или мусора).
Мне необходимо держать Руби машину для запросов(тоесть это не сайт а просто набор скриптов для JSON ответов на запросы десктопного приложения) однако у меня есть пара крошечных страниц которые должны показыватся при попытке зайти на сайт. В них почти нет руби кода просто 1-2 запроса на количество записей в базе данных.  В принципе можно обойтись простым HTML если это поможет увеличить производительность.

Собственно уменя возникло несколько вопросов:

1) в туториалах по развертыванию сервера часто пишут что нужно создавать пользователя DEPLOYER и выдать ему sudo права. Затем все действия ведутся от имени этого пользователя. Или создается группа и права владения выдаются группе. Собственно меня интересует могу ли я все настроить от root пользователя а потом передать право владения папкой проекта deployer-у. Если да то какие файлы придется передавать или лучше создать юзера и все установить от него? Я пробовал передать права только на папку содержащую проэкт и скрипт запуска, но при попытке запустить сервер от не root система говорит о нехватке прав.
[я использовал конфиги и скрипт запуска отсюда](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120368/)
Nginx устанавливал через apt-get.
2) При создании юзера столкнулся с проблемой: после релога перестают действовать клавиши бекспейса и стрелок и вмето привычного

> deployer@server$

я вижу просто

> $

в чем может быть проблема?

3) Во многих туториалах используется гем Capistrano. На сколько я понял это гем для автоматической синхронизации и перезапуска сервера после апдейта git. И он нужен для бесшовного перезапуска сервера. Мне пока сложно дается его настройка. Можно ли как-то проще реализовать бесшовный перезапуск сервера: к примеру я буду апдейтить гит вручную и тогда теоретически будет нужно только перезапустить unicron. Можно ли так реализовать перезапуск или Capistrano лучшый и самый простой вариант?

4)В большинстве туториалов речь идет о серверах с большим количеством сайтов. В моем случае на сервере будет лежать один проект. Если особенности конфигурирования серверов для подобного случая? или отличий небудет просто в конфиге будет 1 блок server?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Советую больше внимания уделить Capistrano. Это гораздо более мощный инструмент, чем вам показалось на первый взгляд. Очень полезная в этом отношении книга A. Burns & T. Copeland "Deploying Rails" будет вам хорошим помощником.

Comment: Спасибо сейчас посмотрю.